# Inconsistencies in the output while reading and writing simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

Why is this code producing an inconsistent output of the reader function?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mu;
int i = 0;

void writeThread()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        printf ("write i: %d\n", ++i);
    }
}

void readThread()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
        printf ("Read i = %d\n", i);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(writeThread);
    std::thread z(readThread);
    t.join();
    z.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I sometimes get something like:

```
write i: 996
write i: 997
Read i = 980 <--- wrong reader output starting here
Read i = 998
Read i = 998
write i: 998
Read i = 998
write i: 999
Read i = 999
```

Is only the output wrong or do I really need a mutex in the reader function?

Comment: In what sense is the output wrong? Why do you think the reader should see any particular value, if there is no synchronisation with the writer? (Strictly speaking this is a data race which has completely undefined behaviour).

Comment: Incidentally for this example you could use atomic types, i.e. `std::atomic_int i = 0` - and not need a mutex at all, and be data-race free, although you still might not see the output you seem to want.

Comment: This particular example is very simple. The program I am working on reads from and writes to STL and some more complex data structures.

Comment: The code has a data race. It's behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is only the output wrong or do I really need a mutex in the reader function?

The output is not wrong, if you have two or more threads accessing a variable and and at least one of them is a writer then you need to provide synchronization.  Since `readThread` does not wait for `WriteThread` to write to `i` you have a race condition.  This is undefined behavior and any output you get is "correct".  To fix this you need to add `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);` to `readThread` like

```
void readThread()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
        printf ("Read i = %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

---

If you have more readers then you have writers you can use a [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) which will allow multiple readers to read at the same time but will block all readers and other writers when one of the writers needs to write.

Comment: I see. So if I have 500 reader threads and each of it blocks the mutex while reading, isn't it as slow as having only one thread?

Comment: @ScepticalJule Just added to the answer about that.